# How to get the root directory

Tags: c#

I have a file path as

```
D:\Accurev\PPF6-AvailableToUse_Test_4_4\eBizSol_App\Source\xyz.txt
```

If I do

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)
```

I get

```
D:\Accurev\PPF6-AvailableToUse_Test_4_4\eBizSol_App\Source
```

But I want to get only the root directory i.e. `"D:\\"`

How can I get it?

N.B.~ Is it possible without string splitting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Path.GetPathRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx) method provided by the framework

> Gets the root directory information of the specified path

For your case you can use:

```
string rootPath = Path.GetPathRoot(filename);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Directory.GetDirectoryRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectoryroot.aspx) Method

Answer (score 3):

```
String pathname= @"D:\Accurev\PPF6-AvailableToUse_Test_4_4\eBizSol_App\Source\xyz.txt";    
string root = Path.GetPathRoot(pathname);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, there're several ways to do the same thing. Here're two of them:

1. [Path.GetRootPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx) as other answers already shown
2. [DirectoryInfo.Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.directoryinfo.root.aspx) property of `FileInfo` class:

   ```
   var fileName=
       @"D:\Accurev\PPF6-AvailableToUse_Test_4_4\eBizSol_App\Source\xyz.txt";

   var file=new FileInfo(fileName);
   var root=file.Directory.Root;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Path.GetPathRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx) Method for this.

- This method gets the root directory information of the specified path.
- It returns the root directory of path, such as "C:\", or null if path is null, or an empty string if path does not contain root directory information.

So, you can simply have `string root = Path.GetPathRoot(fullFileName);`

**But**, this method does not verify that the path or file name exists.

Possible patterns for the string returned by this method are on MSDN as follows:

- An empty string (path specified a relative path on the current drive or volume).
- `"/"` (path specified an absolute path on the current drive).
- `"X:"` (path specified a relative path on a drive, where X represents a drive or volume letter).
- `"X:/"` (path specified an absolute path on a given drive).
- `"\\ComputerName\SharedFolder"` (a UNC path).